# Reading/Writing with Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I have established a TCP connection with a server using

```
String hostName = ...;
int portNumber = ...;
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(hostName, portNumber);
Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
clientSocket.connect(addr, 100);
```

but now I want to send a message to that server.
How do I do that using `InputStreams`?

Comment: You don't. You achieve it with `OutputStreams` and their `write()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of achieving this. Most of the communication done with the Sockets is through their In/OutputStreams. Simple way of sending a message to the socket would be:

```
OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
output.write(Charset.getDefaultCharset().encode("Hello, world!"));
```

The Charset.getDefaultCharset().encode(String) is for converting a String into a byte array, as is it not possible to send any other data than bytes over a socket easily (look up "serialization")

Comment: There actually are easy ways to read or write things other than arrays of bytes. All one has to do is decorate the streams.

Comment: Well i guess thats true ;) But where is the fun in developing you own protocol then ;P

Comment: I would say do not mix data transmission mechanisms with protocols. But I honestly don't get your point there.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the input stream and output stream from a `Socket` with [getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()) and [getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()). From then, you need to use the output stream (not the input stream) to send a message to the server:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
clientSocket.connect(addr, 100);
InputStream istream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream ostream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
 ... // write the message to ostream
 ... // read the server's reply from istream (if applicable)
```

You may want to decorate these streams into other types to facilitate your job as well, as `InputStream` and `OutputStream` are very primitive in terms of operations. For instance, if you want to write a text message, you can use [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(ostream);
writer.print("My number: ");
writer.println(5);
writer.print("My name: ");
writer.println("John Doe");
writer.println("Done");
writer.flush();
```